# Proper Use of QGIS tool: "Frequency analysis"

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, frequency

Trying to use the "Frequency analysis" tool in a script but getting errors.

The Online documentations for this tool:

```
processing.runalg('qgis:frequencyanalysis', input, fields, output)
```

My Script:

```
path = "/Users/User/Desktop/"
PIDs = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('Properties')[0]
field = 'PropertyID'
processing.runalg('qgis:frequencyanalysis', PIDs, field, path+'output')
```

Have also tried:

```
processing.runalg('qgis:frequencyanalysis', PIDs, field, 'output')
```

AND...

```
processing.runalg('qgis:frequencyanalysis', PIDs, field, None)
```

My goal is to simply add a column to the "PIDs" table that for counts the number of times that each row's PID value is in the table.

e.g.

```
PID    FREQUENCY
3459   3
2309   2
0014   1
0187   1
NULL   NULL
3459   3
2309   2
3459   3
```

Any ideas why I'm getting the errors?  I notice that Q's online documentation (above) has the second parameter in plural form, while I only have one field assigned.

Perhaps I am misinterpreting the intention of this tool, and it requires more than one field?  Perhaps my above output example is not what the tool produces?

Comment: Have you tried running **Frequency analysis** directly from the **Processing Toolbox** and then taking a look at the **Processing Log**?  When I do I get the following error: `'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'replace' See log for more details`.

Answer (score 3):

The latest versions of the *Processing* plugin (from 2.10 onwards) contains a couple of errors in the code for the **Frequency Analysis** tool.

You can manually update the tool (located in `C:\Users\You\.qgis2\python\plugins\processing\algs\qgis\scripts`) or create a new script and use the following code, which is directly taken from the tool, but includes the minor fixes (comments show where the updates were made):

```
##Table=group
##Input=vector
##Fields=Field Input
##Frequency=output table

from processing.tools.vector import TableWriter
from collections import defaultdict
from processing.core.GeoAlgorithmExecutionException import GeoAlgorithmExecutionException

layer = processing.getObject(Input)    # Changed '(input)' to '(Input)'
inputFields = layer.pendingFields()
fieldIdxs = []
fields = Fields.split(',')    # Changed 'fields.split' to 'Fields.split'
for f in fields:
    idx = inputFields.indexFromName(f)
    if idx == -1:
        raise GeoAlgorithmExecutionException('Field not found:' + f)
    fieldIdxs.append(idx)
writer = TableWriter(Frequency, None, fields + ['FREQ'])    # Changed 'output' to 'Frequency'

counts = {}
feats = processing.features(layer)
nFeats = len(feats)
counts = defaultdict(int)
for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
    progress.setPercentage(int(100 * i / nFeats))
    attrs = feat.attributes()
    clazz = tuple([attrs[i] for i in fieldIdxs])
    print clazz
    counts[clazz] += 1

for c in counts:
    writer.addRecord(list(c) + [counts[c]])
```

I also changed the `Fields` parameter to list the available fields instead of forcing the user to type it as a string:

[image: Frequency Analysis]

[image: Results]

---

Also tested using the **Python Console** (using similar format you had) and outputs a .csv file successfully.

Comment: A [bug report](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/14090) has been submitted.